# Assigning student positions like 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc based on their scores in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please how can I achieve this in ASP.NET MVC View: Assign 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc counting from highest student score to the least. Where two or more student score the same, they get same position and the next highest get the next position. Note that the Scores is stored in my StudentAssessment table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple have two local variables on your view to store the rank and the previous score in the list. Whenever the previousScore and current score values are different, you can increment your rank counter by 1.

I've assumed your view is strongly typed and receives a list of score from its action.

Please check the code below.

```
@{
    int rank = 0, previousScore=0;
}
    @foreach(var item in Model.OrderByDescending(a=>a.score)) {
        if(item.score !=previousScore) {
        rank += 1;  
        }
        previousScore = item.score;

    <span> @rank) @item.name , @item.score </span> 
    <br />      
}
```